# Not able to align text in center in UI element

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-lists

I am not able to align text in center in UI element

Here is the code

```
<div id="holder4" class="holder" style="height: 450px; width: 1210px;">
  <ul id="place18" class="place ui-selectable">
    <li data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Row" data-content="Seat No:B3 Price: 100 GBP" class="seat ui-selectee" style="top:0px;left:81px">222</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiranSaj/m2tqmdbm/1/).

I want to show no at exact center of `li` element.

Comment: what's with all the positioning? How is this supposed to look?

Comment: Text suppose to be center aligned.

Comment: I have removed unwanted code. Can you please check now. The LI is using .place .seat class

Comment: Remove your `width: 3px` : text will be center aligned. If you want the `li`to stay square, adapt padding on left and right (`padding: 10px 4px` for example).

Comment: But removing width:3px will hamper the shape. It not right solution.

Comment: The text is too long to fit in 3px so it's not logical.

Comment: But I can see there is space before the text? I want to retain the shape. What could be the solution?

Comment: Exactly as @Paulie_D said. And `line-height: 0` has no sense either... Text is center aligned here : https://jsfiddle.net/qp2y8nc2/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering your markup, you can wrap the number into a `<span>` and use absolute positioning to center the element.

Try this
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guruwanabe/m2tqmdbm/4/)

Comment: I have not down voted it. Actually I want to vote it. Pleas help/